# Need help with my financial situation/life, very unhappy

Tags: student-loan, education

I am 24 and have $21,000 in student loans and no degree. I dropped out of college because I wasn't sure what I wanted to do and for my last quarter I took F's. Now I can't go back and get financial aid without paying full price for one quarter (about $3000). I still have at least 2 years left for a degree(math). And I don't know if I want to do that. I think I might be better fit for something else.

I am about to start working minimum wage and I plan to save as much of that money as I can. For the last two years I have been living with my parents working less than part time. However, I have been able to make all my student loan payments, because I am really good at saving the little money I do make. I want to turn my life around.

I am thinking of going to community college (I think I can get fin. aid there) and finding a 2-year program that can help me get a job paying better than minimum. I don't know what type of degree to go for though. Does anyone have advice for me?

Comment: **2 years left for a degree(math)**. I would heartily ask you to consider finishing it, but I would prefer to do it only if I put my heart and soul into it. Completing it with a GPA of around 3.5-4 is much more acceptable than finishing it with a 2.5. Economy in US seems to be picking up, and I would believe those 2 years well spent will be fruitful. With a good degree even if jobs are scarce, chances of applying for a Masters or PhD with full scholarship will also be an option. Do this only if you have an aptitude for a higher education.

Comment: Keep in mind that you haven't specified where in the world you are nor what interests you have other than a waning interest in Math.  So what else would you like to do?  What kinds of opportunities are near you?  These are questions that are hard to answer without more details.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this borders on not really in keeping with the site guidelines, since there is no real question being asked other than, "What should I do?" and that is discussion/opinion based.  That said, there probably are many constructive things you can do, and gathering information is a great first step!  Could you edit your question to provide more detail as @JBKing mentioned in a comment?  Maybe the question can be better focused, too.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider going to take an aptitude test. It might help you figure out and focus on a new direction to take your life.